# Robots.txt Disallow command

Tags: search-engines, robots.txt, duplicate-content

How do I use *robots.txt* to disallow folders which are being crawled due to a bad URL structure? They're currently causing a duplicate page error.

The URL which been crawled incorrectly is:

```
www.abc.com/forum/index.php?option=com_forum
```

However, The correct page is:

```
www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_forum
```

Is *robots.txt* a correct way of excluding this? I'm thinking about using:

```
Disallow: /forum/
```

Will that not block legitimate content in the `/forum/` folder of my site?

Comment: If `/forum/index.php?option=com_forum` isn't the correct URL, what are you serving when a crawler hits that page?  The correct thing would be to serve a 404 not found error, or a redirect to where the page actually exists.  If you do that, you will have no problems with duplicate pages.

Answer (score 1):

If `www.abc.com/forum/index.php?option=com_forum` is the only link that's been mis-read then you can just add `Disallow: /forum/index.php` to your *robots.txt* file. Adding `Disallow: /forum/` will tell robots to ignore *everything* in that directory, which doesn't sound like what you want.

You could also add a 301 redirect from `www.abc.com/forum/index.php?option=com_forum` to `www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_forum` to tell robots what the URL should be. This will also help any users who accidentally land on the wrong URL.

Comment: Thanks, Actually there are close to 100's of urls been crawled like this. Forum was an example. It has been crawled on with some say toys also . Now toys folder do not exist in site, but still google has crawled the site with toys. Will a command like Disallow: /forum/ or Disallow: /toys/ is apt to make Google stop crawling up urls